# how to convert an image into base 64 in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i just don't know how to convert an image into base 64 from a controller! the conversion code works fine when i have a script tag inside my html code!i am new to angular-js!Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy your java script inside the controller of your angularjs! it will work!